# Why does a property inherited from an interface become virtual?

Tags: c#, reflection

Say I have one interface and two classes, and one of the classes implement this interface:

```
interface IAAA
{
    int F1 { get; set; }
}

class AAA1
{
    public int F1 { get; set; }
    public int F2 { get; set; }
}

class AAA2 : IAAA
{
    public int F1 { get; set; }
    public int F2 { get; set; }
}
```

In class `AAA2`, property `F1` is 'inherited' (I'm not sure) from interface `IAAA`, then I use reflection to check whether a property is virtual:

```
Console.WriteLine("AAA1 which does not implement IAAA");
foreach (var prop in typeof(AAA1).GetProperties())
{
    var virtualOrNot = prop.GetGetMethod().IsVirtual ? "" : " not";
    Console.WriteLine($@"{prop.Name} is{virtualOrNot} virtual");
}

Console.WriteLine("AAA2 which implements IAAA");
foreach (var prop in typeof(AAA2).GetProperties())
{
    var virtualOrNot = prop.GetGetMethod().IsVirtual ? "" : " not";
    Console.WriteLine($"{prop.Name} is{virtualOrNot} virtual");
}
```

The output is:

```
AAA1 which does not implement IAAA
F1 is not virtual
F2 is not virtual
AAA2 which implements IAAA
F1 is virtual
F2 is not virtual
```

Any reason for this?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

As from [remarks section of MS docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.methodbase.isvirtual?view=netframework-4.7.2#remarks):

> A virtual member may reference instance data in a class and must be referenced through an instance of the class...  The common language runtime requires that all methods that implement interface members must be marked as virtual; therefore, the compiler marks the method `virtual final`

If you need to determine whether this method is overridable then checking `IsVirtual` is not enough and you need to also check that `IsFinal` is false.

Here is an extension method that do this check:

```
public static bool IsOverridable(this MethodInfo method)
    => method.IsVirtual && !method.IsFinal;
```

Comment: Your method also returns false for a method (or getter/setter of a property etc.) declared `sealed override` in C# (whether it implements an interface or not). Checking `.IsVirtual` alone in these cases would yield true.